# Collapse jQuery menu and add style

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, styles

I was hoping one of you guys maybe able to help me with something I am creating. I am creating a tree style menu that will open up documents on my computer. So far the code below is what I have created. My issue is I want it to be fully collapsed when opening and not showing the contents unless clicked on. How would I go about doing this? I also want little plus arrows that change into minus symbols when clicked, instead of bullet points, any ideas? (I am kinda new to all this stuff)

Thanks

Please note my code can be seen here http://cdpn.io/GtLky working (but needs the amendments above) ﻿

or the full on code in this section below

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<p><font size=4>This is a test</font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                <body>
<ul>
    <li><span class="Collapsable">Test 1</span><ul>
        <li><span class="Collapsable">I like cats</span></li>
        <li><span class="Collapsable">Cats rule</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="Collapsable">This is a test 2</span><ul>
        <li><span class="Collapsable">Cat love</span></li>
        <li><span class="Collapsable">testy cat</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="Collapsable">This is a test 3</span><ul>
        <li><span class="Collapsable">Master Cat</span></li>
        <li><span class="Collapsable"><a href = "http://www.nme.com">NME</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".Collapsable").click(function () {

        $(this).parent().children().toggle();
        $(this).toggle();

    });


</script>
```

Comment: It appears that you are essentially trying to create a tree view. There are several jQuery plugins that already do that. Some of them can be found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned some things up a bit with the `.Collapsable` elements and made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxinacube/UYPNf/) to demonstrate.

Basically, we simplify the HTML and beef up the jQuery.

Comment: Maxinacube... Wow thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to do. How would I collapse the first menu though, so all menus are collapsed? Any ideas also how I would add a Plus instead of bullet points and a minus for when a menu is open?

Comment: My other issue is that it all needs to be in 1 html document if possible. So all this needs to be pasted into notepad, saved as HTML and then run. Hence why pulling commands from the "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"

Comment: I've updated to Fiddle to show how you can have them all collapsed. There is a line in the jQuery that was showing the first, but if we remove that all will be collapsed.

I also added a part in the jQuery to insert a `span` as the first item in `li.collapsable`. Using a CSS pseudo-class (`:after`) we can set the content for the `span` to "+" or "-" if `.collapsable` has class `.active`

To put it all in one document just set it up the way you had before, with the custom scripts at the bottom. Just include a `<style>` tag in the head with the CSS.

Comment: Hi Maxincube. I really like what you have made. I have created this. Ive finally got something kind of working. Only issue now is ive hit a stumbling block. Ive decided to split this all up into css, java etc using jsdidle (much better than codepen) my issue is that if I add a submenu within a submenu I loose the arrow and it opens up the submenu item by default. Any idea how I can add an arrow onto the submenu and stop it opening by default and only on mouse click? http://jsfiddle.net/neosegauk/rtkeR/4/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks ever so much for the help. This worked a treat with all the feedback.